# Importing big MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

I am trying to import a 6GB database on RHEL7.
I have been reading for
Here are my main settings in my.cnf:
Why downvote? You are just making sure nobody else will help who needs help.
Please let me know what is wrong with the question and I'll update with information

```
debug-info = TRUE
max_allowed_packet=8200M;
net_buffer_length=1000000M;
post_max_size=4096M
max_exection_time = 60 * 60;
upload_max_filesize=6000M
read_buffer_size = 2014K
connect_timeout = 1000000
net_write_timeout = 1000000
wait_timeout = 1000000
memory_limit=6000M
```

After changing my settings I restarted the mysql service and then

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%max%';
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                                        | Value                |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time                          | 0                    |
| ft_max_word_len                                      | 84                   |
| group_concat_max_len                                 | 1024                 |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay                      | 150000               |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size                        | 25                   |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max                       | 50                   |
| innodb_file_format_max                               | Barracuda            |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                             | 84                   |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                               | 2000                 |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                           | 75.000000            |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm                       | 0.000000             |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                                 | 0                    |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay                           | 0                    |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                             | 1073741824           |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size                     | 134217728            |
| max_allowed_packet                                   | 4194304              |
| max_binlog_cache_size                                | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                                      | 1073741824           |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                           | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_connect_errors                                   | 100                  |
| max_connections                                      | 151                  |
| max_delayed_threads                                  | 20                   |
| max_digest_length                                    | 1024                 |
| max_error_count                                      | 64                   |
| max_execution_time                                   | 0                    |
| max_heap_table_size                                  | 16777216             |
| max_insert_delayed_threads                           | 20                   |
| max_join_size                                        | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_length_for_sort_data                             | 1024                 |
| max_points_in_geometry                               | 65536                |
| max_prepared_stmt_count                              | 16382                |
| max_relay_log_size                                   | 0                    |
| max_seeks_for_key                                    | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_sort_length                                      | 1024                 |
| max_sp_recursion_depth                               | 0                    |
| max_tmp_tables                                       | 32                   |
| max_user_connections                                 | 0                    |
| max_write_lock_count                                 | 18446744073709551615 |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size                            | 9223372036853727232  |
| optimizer_trace_max_mem_size                         | 16384                |
| parser_max_mem_size                                  | 18446744073709551615 |
| performance_schema_max_cond_classes                  | 80                   |
| performance_schema_max_cond_instances                | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_digest_length                 | 1024                 |
| performance_schema_max_file_classes                  | 80                   |
| performance_schema_max_file_handles                  | 32768                |
| performance_schema_max_file_instances                | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_index_stat                    | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_memory_classes                | 320                  |
| performance_schema_max_metadata_locks                | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_mutex_classes                 | 210                  |
| performance_schema_max_mutex_instances               | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_program_instances             | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes                | 40                   |
| performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances              | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_socket_classes                | 10                   |
| performance_schema_max_socket_instances              | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_sql_text_length               | 1024                 |
| performance_schema_max_stage_classes                 | 150                  |
| performance_schema_max_statement_classes             | 193                  |
| performance_schema_max_statement_stack               | 10                   |
| performance_schema_max_table_handles                 | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_table_instances               | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat               | -1                   |
| performance_schema_max_thread_classes                | 50                   |
| performance_schema_max_thread_instances              | -1                   |
| range_optimizer_max_mem_size                         | 8388608              |
| slave_max_allowed_packet                             | 1073741824           |
| slave_pending_jobs_size_max                          | 16777216             |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

70 rows in set (0.01 sec)

$ mysql -u user -p database_name < database_dump.sql  --force --wait --reconnect

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 4432: MySQL server has gone away
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 4433: MySQL server has gone away
...
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 5707: MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: please look into the mysql error logs, because it should not have a timeout

Comment: 1) Looks like you have edited wrong file (server uses some another config file). 2) Set needed variables for a session immediately before importing. 3) Look carefully everything inserted into config files for typos.

Comment: I notice you tried to set `max_allowed_packet=8200M` but the largest value you can use is 1024M. You can see in the output of your settings after restart that the value is still 4M, so it basically ignored the invalid setting. So if you have any rows larger than that, it'll cause the connection to drop.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I was simply editing the wrong my.cnf file and had 3 php.ini instructions in there.
Correct answer would be setting:

etc/opt/rh/rh-mysql57/my.cnf

```
debug-info = TRUE
max_allowed_packet=1024M;
net_buffer_length=1000000M;
upload_max_filesize=6000M
read_buffer_size = 2014K
connect_timeout = 1000000
net_write_timeout = 1000000
wait_timeout = 1000000
```

This should work for bigger databases.